# doxygen graphviz rename node name (from "data path + file name" to only the "file name")

Tags: doxygen, graphviz

I'm looking for an answer now quite a while but I could not find one slightly simular one.
I'm pretty new to the whole DoxyGen + GraphViz thing. But I love it so far.

My problem is I'm a visual person, and I have to get my hands on a big project for my BA Thesis.

For this I'd like that the tree nodes are as simple as possible.
So I get some tree nods with only the name of the file like "header.h" and in the next tree I get the same node with the whole filename + data path like "c:\testfolder\source\header.h".

My question is how can I change that so that I only get the filename in every graph and node ?

Here is an example picture, als a link for you.

http://img5.fotos-hochladen.net/uploads/doxygenakiex2mwzg.jpg

in this example they are not the same files but still you can see my problem
Sry for my poor english hope you got the hang of it. Thank you so much for your help.

kind regards

Danny

Comment: Are these the class diagrams auto generated by doxygen, or ones you manually created?

Comment: Hi, they are auto generated by doxygen with the plugin graphviz

Comment: Try changing your config to `FULL_PATH_NAMES = YES` I know that will work in the HTML, not sure about the graphs.

Comment: Hi Denise, thank you so much for your suggestion. But FULL_PATH_NAMES is in my config on YES. Do you have any other suggestions ?

Comment: Do you have anything set for `STRIP_FROM_PATH` `STRIP_FROM_INC_PATH` or `INCLUDE_PATH`  Are you getting full path names everywhere else, just not in the diagrams?

Comment: Oh wait, you want partial paths, not full paths, change to `FULL_PATH_NAMES = NO`

Comment: thats the solution for me with the:

FULL_PATH_NAMES = NO

thank you so much Denise

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set `FULL_PATH_NAMES = NO` in your Doxygen Config